# Reconstructing github page from url modified with pushState/popstate

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I'm trying to build a small homepage hosted on github-pages, with a (1) title, (2) navbar and (3) a content window. I'm updating the content with ajax and use pushState/popstate for url updating and browser history. The problem is that if one *refreshes* the page at e.g. user.github.io/content1, the page is not found (because the html file doesn't actually exist).

I read that if one controls the server, this is usually solved by redirecting (or mod_rewrite-ing) every requested deep link to one resource and from there reconstructing the page with javascript according to the requested link. On gh-pages, this is not possible, so I thought about actually creating all the html files reflecting the url paths, but with each of them only containing the javascript code to re-generate the corresponding state (so that e.g. if I want to update my title or the links in the navbar, I don't have to manually edit all of the html files).

I have read about Jekyll, but I'm a beginner and I'd like to program everything from scratch to learn something.

Do you think this approach is a waste of time? Are there better ways to do this?

Thanks a lot, Stefan

Comment: Any god reason to use ajax loading vs static html ? If you're doing something else than a Single Page Application, you must go static = Simpler code + better performance.

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: When you say "static html", do you mean that the pages user.github.io/content1, user.github.io/content2, ... user.github.io/contentN should all be self-contained html files including the title and navigation bar? So if I added a user.github.io/content(N+1), I'd had to open up N html files to add the new link (link N+1) to the navigation bar. That's what I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two cases :

### Making a Single Page Applivation (SPA)

Your SPA is a javascript application that needs to send datas to/from a server that stores them, and to render the results on the client side.

In this case, your problem is not a Jekyll problem, it's a data one.
You can then have a serious look at react, angular and so on, ...

### Making static web pages

[Github pages](https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/) is using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) to [generate static pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/).

This way you can generate static pages with a title, a specific navbar and content with nothing more.

In terms of development and performance, it will be far more efficient.

### Why it's better ?

Still assuming that you're not building an SPA.

Anytime you make a change in gh-pages (anything new like page, post, ...), your site is rebuild (post, page, include like navigation, an so on).

New page -> commit to gh-pages -> new build -> everything is OK !